# Datepicker not selecting correct date

Tags: javascript, jquery

date is a value from a jquery datepicker, I am wanting to return the last date of the next month if > 27th is picked in the datepicker, but the below is always selecting the last day of the next month whether its > the 27th or not?

```
if (date > date.getMonth(date.getDate() + 0, 27))
{
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 2, 0);
}
else {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

Comment: If `date` is a [JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) it does not accept parameters to any of those getter functions. What are you expecting this to do?

Answer (score 1):

To get the day of the month, you should use [`Date.prototype.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate):

```
if (date.getDate() > 27)
{
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

Probably, your variable `date` is a `String`, and if so, then, first you must convert it to a `Date` object:

```
date = new Date(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need an `else` block. Just check the date that was selected with `.getDate()`. No need to check the month.

To get the date selected, use: `var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');` and then `if (date.getDate() > 27)`. That's all you need.

Complete code:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (date.getDate() > 27)
        {
          $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0));
        }
    }
});
```

And a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ugwtkpp1/1/